# Get Current Timer shortcut now working as intended on WatchOS

Tags: apple-watch, shortcuts-app, watchos

I am trying to create a Shortcut that sets a timer based on an input and then retrieve the duration of the timer using the Get Current Timer action (see image below). However, it appears that the Get Current Timer action does not have the intended result in WatchOS. When I set the timer to 5 minutes, the notification indicates 0s. The Apple Watch is on WatchOS 10.1.1.

The same Shortcut works as intended on the iPhone, and the notification indicates 300s.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug on watchOS. I'd [report it to Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Here's a workaround that involves getting the difference in time between two calendar dates (although this complexity isn't shown when the Shortcut is run, it just asks for a duration):
[image: Screenshot of Shortcuts app]

The 'Add 1 minute to Chosen Date' action is to fix an inaccuracy in how duration is calculated in the 'Get time between dates' action.

The only downside to this approach is that you'll only be able to set a timer in whole minutes.

[iCloud link for Shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/a2124e7bb82b45d9b58ff97f943c0599)